# is there a way to tell lxde desktop to "execute" script when double clicking on it?

Tags: remote-desktop, fedora, shortcuts, vnc, lxde

i'm using lxde desktop, Fedora 20, and i symlinked a shell script to desktop to set resolution and dpi when i use vnc.

but everytime i click on the script, it ask me to execute or open it, how to make it always "execute" ?

[image]

and btw, why can't in run

```
xrandr -s 1280x800 --dpi 97
```

but have to run

```
xrandr -s 1280x800 && xrandr --dpi 97
```

can't set resolution and dpi at the same time ?